# Eval list within quotes

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input, eval

I am writing a program in Python that takes in user input (not using Python's built-in `input`) that is a string that contains a list of strings, ie. `'["hello", "world"]'`. However, some inputs will have multiple quotes inside, ie. `'["Hello", "wor"ld"]'`. I need the string to always `eval()` to a list. Any advice on cleansing the input string to ensure that it will always eval? Already tried `.replace('"', '\"')`.

Comment: first of all... don't use `eval`...

Comment: You're better off using `json.loads`. Also, I would recommend you throw an error than break your head. If a user is going to enter input like that, chances are they're horsing around.

Comment: So, there are just double-quote chars randomly interspersed in the string? That's going to be hugely problematic to deal with in the general case.

Comment: Find another way to do this, eval is just leaving huge security holes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat difficult problem because it is hard for the computer to know which of the quotations are extraneous and which are the intended ones. The best solution which i can think of would be to first remove all double quotes and spaces, then add back in double quotes after any instance of the characters "[", insert a space and double quotes after any comma, and insert double quotes before every comma and "]". This is not an elegant solution and may take a few lines of code but unless you can sanitize the input earlier in the program this is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I almost hate myself for doing this, but it may actually work. First, select a symbol that is not going to be entered by the user, ever (e.g., 字 or ~). Then, remove the valid quotation marks at the beginning at the end and replace all *valid* quotation marks between items by that symbol:

```
s = '["Hello", "wor",ld"  , " ]'
s1 = re.sub(r"(\[\s*\")|(\"\s*,?\s*\])", "", s)
# 'Hello", "wor",ld"  , '
s1 = re.sub(r"\"\s*,\s*\"", "字", s1)
# 'Hello字wor",ld"  , '
```

Finally, escape all remaining double quotes, replace the funny symbols with the item separators, and add the brackets:

```
result = '["' + s1.replace('"', r'\"').replace("字",'","') + '"]'
#'["Hello","wor\\",ld\\"  , "]'
ast.literal_eval(result)
#['Hello', 'wor",ld"  , ']
```